# variant is doesn't apply on formControl input field

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to have a field with a variant outlined, I can't use the `TextField` component because I want to have an `endAdornment` inside the input.

The problem is that the style is not being applied, even though I am specifying the `variant='outlined'` property on the `FormControl` component.

- Using **mui/material 5.6.3**

```js
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl'
import Input from '@mui/material/Input'
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel'
import FormHelperText from '@mui/material/FormHelperText'
import InputAdornment from '@mui/material/InputAdornment'

          <FormControl variant="outlined" fullWidth>
            <InputLabel required>
              password
            </InputLabel>
            <Input
              type='text'
              endAdornment={
                <InputAdornment position="end">
                    <IconButton onClick={handleShowPassword} edge="end">
                       <VisibilityOff />
                    </IconButton>
                </InputAdornment>
              }
              value=" ... "
              onChange={()=>{ / * ... */ }}
            />
            <FormHelperText>Will be used to login to your account</FormHelperText>
          </FormControl>
```

showing:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use the `TextField` component from Material UI to achieve a outlined input field. Refer the API link https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/

Just note that you have to provide the variant to the `textfield` component.
Use the `InputProps` in order to have the icons inside the component.
Working demo link : [CodeSandbox Live](https://codesandbox.io/s/basictextfields-material-demo-forked-w4lsz6?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Aha, so it's a bug in MUI, I knew that. Thank you @jarivak

Answer (score 0):

I was just struggling with a similar challenge, trying to put a label of type JSX.Element on a TextField.
As I understand this, the issue is not a "bug" but a matter of knowing which components to use. Within the FormControl we don't use TextField and set `variant`. We use a different base input control for the variant that we want to use.

Here are examples that demonstrate how to use the different input types, **and** some options for using labels within the FormControl:

```
  const labelStyle = {
    color: 'blue',
  }
  const inputStyle = {
    width: '100px',
  }
  const savedLabel = <Label style={{color: 'green'}}>Outlined</Label>
  return (
    <>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel>{<Label style={labelStyle}>Standard</Label>}</FormLabel>
        <Input style={inputStyle} />
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel>{savedLabel}</FormLabel>
        <OutlinedInput style={inputStyle} />
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel>
          <Label style={labelStyle}>Filled</Label>
        </FormLabel>
        <FilledInput style={inputStyle} />
      </FormControl>
      <MuiTextField style={inputStyle} label="TextField" />
    </>
  )
```

[image: screenshot of code output]

There is an anomaly to note in the screenshot. The OutlinedInput control with a separate label gets the outline (grey box) rendered over the label (green), where the TextField using a string leaves a gap in the field container for the text label.

"So why is there a seemingly redundant `variant` property on `FormControl`?"
I dunno - I'm thinking it works with other nested controls.

"Why not use `InputLabel`?"
Substituting InputLabel for FormLabel in the above code breaks all of the FormControl labels. I dunno why.

I don't claim to be an expert in this area, and I don't claim this is the right or only way to do this. I'm just saying this works, and this *seems* to be the intended way to use these controls in this very specific context, and thus, I don't believe it's a "bug".

I'm learning a lot about MUI as I create wrapper controls over them and exercise their ability to morph through composition. There is a lot to learn in this area. If I come to understand more later I'll post back here.